# how to save cropped image

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jcrop

Downloaded the code for cropping image from the following link:

http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html

This is the code in crop.php page:

```
<?php

/**
 * Jcrop image cropping plugin for jQuery
 * Example cropping script
 * @copyright 2008-2009 Kelly Hallman
 * More info: http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop_Implementation_Theory.html
 */

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    $targ_w = $targ_h = 150;
    $jpeg_quality = 90;

    $src = 'demo_files/pool.jpg';
    $img_r = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
    $dst_r = ImageCreateTrueColor( $targ_w, $targ_h );

    imagecopyresampled($dst_r,$img_r,0,0,$_POST['x'],$_POST['y'],
    $targ_w,$targ_h,$_POST['w'],$_POST['h']);

    header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
    imagejpeg($dst_r,null,$jpeg_quality);

    exit;
}

// If not a POST request, display page below:

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
        <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.Jcrop.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.Jcrop.css" type="text/css" />
        <script language="Javascript">

            $(function(){

                $('#cropbox').Jcrop({
                    aspectRatio: 1,
                    onSelect: updateCoords
                });

            });

            function updateCoords(c)
            {
                $('#x').val(c.x);
                $('#y').val(c.y);
                $('#w').val(c.w);
                $('#h').val(c.h);
            };

            function checkCoords()
            {
                if (parseInt($('#w').val())) return true;
                alert('Please select a crop region then press submit.');
                return false;
            };

        </script>

</head>

<body>
<!-- This is the image we're attaching Jcrop to -->
        <img src="demo_files/pool.jpg" id="cropbox" />

        <!-- This is the form that our event handler fills -->
        <form action="crop.php" method="post" onsubmit="return checkCoords();">
            <input type="hidden" id="x" name="x" />
            <input type="hidden" id="y" name="y" />
            <input type="hidden" id="w" name="w" />
            <input type="hidden" id="h" name="h" />
            <input type="submit" value="Crop Image" />
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The cropping is done perfectly and displayed the cropped image successfully.

But i want to save the cropped image into a directory .

How can i do this?

Comment: Have you read the manual on [`imagejpeg`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php)? Change the second parameter from `null` to the desired filename.

Comment: +1 @Josh, do it like this `ImageJpeg($dst_r, 'images/' . 'Desired_name';` To save the file into `images` directory. Read more here http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php

Comment: @Joy,I changed the code as `imagejpeg($dst_r,'crop_images/',$jpeg_quality);`.Then i got this error `The image “http://localhost/crop/index.php” cannot be displayed because it contains errors.`

Comment: @galtech.Mariya, Do you still want to show the image, if you do you Can Just link to the newly saved image from images dir. Remove the `header('Content-type: image/jpeg');` It will remove the error.

Comment: +1@Joy,ok i got my mistake , only put the disrectory path not included the name of the image

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
imagejpeg($dst_r, 'yourfilename.jpg', $jpeg_quality);

// Remove from memory - don't forget this part
imagedestroy($dst_r);
```

More info
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it.

Change this:

```
imagejpeg($dst_r,$src,$jpeg_quality);
```

to

```
imagejpeg($dst_r);// Output


imagedestroy($dst_r);// Free the memory
```